# HTML5 video player not working for Twitter videos

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, twitter, html5-video

I am retrieving tweets via the Twitter api and attempting to embed their video attachments.

**Embed Code:**

```html
    <video controls="">
      <source src="https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1444247208514113546/pu/vid/1280x720/6rw0rzMWMSk39eoz.mp4?tag=12" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

**Firefox:**

The above code fails to render the video player altogether in firefox, choosing instead to simply return: `No video with supported format and MIME type found`.

[image: Firefox fails to load the video]

Note: There is no issue in playback when the video url is entered directly into the address bar.

**Chrome:**

Chrome spontaneously stops playback after 0-4 seconds, returning to the first frame. This behavior is somewhat sporadic, occurring sometimes, but not always. When it does occur, no matter how many times the play button is pressed, the video is unable to progress any further. Once a video is in memory and has been successfully loaded by refreshing the page, it no longer behaves in this way. Like firefox, there is no issue in loading or playback if the video url is entered directly into the address bar.

[Video demonstration:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSQqcravWEQ)

Some more examples of twitter videos to [play with](https://codepen.io/perrelet/pen/GREVGbr):

Comment: can you please make the YouTube video public

Comment: @TERMINATOR apologies - done!

Comment: I seesm you have a bad cookie from twiter

Answer (score 0):

Many site issues such as the `No video with supported format and MIME type found` error  can be caused by corrupted cookies or cache.This can cause streaming problems in any browser

### Firefox Solution:

I suggest you Clear the Cache and Remove Cookies in your settings
Warning ! ! This will log you out of sites you're logged in to.

To do this enter `about:preferences` in the url bar.

1. **To clear Cookies:** Select `Privacy` under `History`, then select `Firefox will Use Custom Settings`. Press the button on the right side called `Show Cookies`, then use the search bar to look for the site. There may be more than one cookie in use for this site. Remove All of them.
2. **To clear cache:** Select `Advanced > Network`. Across from Cached Web Content, Press Clear Now.
   If there is still a problem, Start Firefox in Safe Mode {web link} While you are in safe mode;

Then restart.

---

### Chrome solution:

1. At the top right, click the  `More` button
2. Navigate to `More tools > Clear browsing data` .
3. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All time.
4. Next to `Cookies and other site data` and `Cached images and files,` check the boxes.
5. Click the `Clear data` button.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it isn't cookies / browsing data as it still happens with cookies + cache cleared, in incognito mode and with the embed code rendered on any arbitrary domain. Despite this, the issue does not appear to effect other machines I have tested or other users on this machine.